# How to query AWS RedShift from AWS Glue PySpark Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have a redshift cluster which is not publicly accessible. I want to query the database in cluster from glue job using pyspark. I have tried this snippet but I'm getting timed out error.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Glue to RedShift") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshift-cluster-***************redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev") \
  .option("user","******") \
  .option("password","************") \
  .option("query", "Select * from category limit 10") \
  .option("tempdir", "s3a://e-commerce-website-templates/ahmad") \
  .option("aws_iam_role", "arn:aws:iam::337618512328:role/glue_s3_redshift") \
  .load()
df.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a Glue Connection to Redshift?

Comment: I tried adding a connection but it failed.

Comment: It is really hard from only this code to see what could be the problem. You need to provide more context -> is Redshift in a private or public subnet, do you have a Glue Connection Object etc.